# REST api not working on installed server

Tags: .net, rest, api

I am implementing a RestApi in .Net and for authentication I am using sha512 for verifying password but while I try to test that Api on installed server, it is not working but on other system or other server it is working fine.

I am using Oauth for authentication.

Here is some code to verify password and web configuration  file.

web.config

[image]

[image]

varify password

```
public static bool VerifyHash(string plainText, string hashAlgorithm, string hashValue)
    {

        // Convert base64-encoded hash value into a byte array.
        byte[] hashWithSaltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);

        // We must know size of hash (without salt).
        int hashSizeInBits, hashSizeInBytes;

        // Make sure that hashing algorithm name is specified.
        if (hashAlgorithm == null)
            hashAlgorithm = "";

        // Size of hash is based on the specified algorithm.
        switch (hashAlgorithm.ToUpper())
        {

            case "SHA384":
                hashSizeInBits = 384;
                break;

            case "SHA512":
                hashSizeInBits = 512;
                break;

            default: // Must be MD5
                hashSizeInBits = 128;
                break;
        }

        // Convert size of hash from bits to bytes.
        hashSizeInBytes = hashSizeInBits / 8;

        // Make sure that the specified hash value is long enough.
        if (hashWithSaltBytes.Length < hashSizeInBytes)
            return false;

        // Allocate array to hold original salt bytes retrieved from hash.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[hashWithSaltBytes.Length - hashSizeInBytes];

        // Copy salt from the end of the hash to the new array.
        for (int i = 0; i < saltBytes.Length; i++)
            saltBytes[i] = hashWithSaltBytes[hashSizeInBytes + i];

        // Compute a new hash string.
        string expectedHashString = ComputeHash(plainText, hashAlgorithm, saltBytes);

        // If the computed hash matches the specified hash,
        // the plain text value must be correct.
        return (hashValue == expectedHashString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem with adding this line of code in config file.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```